# How to repeat a cell a set number of times in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-online

I have two columns, the first with a description of an item, the second with the quantity of the item.  I'd like to turn this into a list of the described items. I need the solution to work on Windows/Mac/Web, so FILTERXML or VBA won't work. In Google Sheets I can use REPT and SPLIT in an ARRAYFORMULA, but I'm not seeing an Excel equivalent to SPLIT.  Any ideas on how to make this happen?

**Start with this:**

| Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | 4 |
| Oranges | 3 |

**End with this:**

| Items |
| --- |
| Apples |
| Apples |
| Apples |
| Apples |
| Oranges |
| Oranges |
| Oranges |

My example source data above is a simple 2x2 array `{"Apples", 4; "Oranges", 3}` but it should be noted that my actual data will be much larger.  I am developing a shared template for  budget items and don't know in advance the actual number of rows (could be hundreds), the length of the strings, nor the quantities of each item (could also be in the hundreds).

I found I can created an array from one row to using any of the following:

```
=MAKEARRAY(B1,1,LAMBDA(r,c,A1))

=TEXTSPLIT(LAMBDA(type,count,REPT(type & "|",count))(A1,B1),,"|",TRUE)

=LAMBDA(item,quantity, SUBSTITUTE(item," ","",SEQUENCE(quantity)))(A1,B1)
```

All the above produce

| Items |
| --- |
| Apples |
| Apples |
| Apples |
| Apples |

But, if I try to adapt any to multiple rows using one of the following, I get a `#CALC` error that *"Nested arrays are not supported"*:

```
=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2, LAMBDA(item,quantity,MAKEARRAY(quantity,1,LAMBDA(r,c,item))))

=BYROW(A1:A2,LAMBDA(rows,TEXTSPLIT( MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(type,count,REPT(type & "|",count))),,"|",TRUE)))

=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2, LAMBDA(item,quantity, SUBSTITUTE(item," ","",SEQUENCE(quantity))))
```

I just don't know how to append the next row's results to combine the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Excel, use the `TEXTSPLIT` function to achieve the same result.

##### Syntax

[TEXTSPLIT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7)

```
=TEXTSPLIT(text,col_delimiter,[row_delimiter],[ignore_empty], [match_mode], [pad_with])
```

##### LAMBDA Formula: Option 1

With or without `VSTACK`, this is the simpler of the two approaches.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1,
      BYROW(A2:B4,
         LAMBDA(x, ARRAYTOTEXT(MAKEARRAY(INDEX(x,1,2),1,
            LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(x, 1, 1))))))),,", ")
```

<kbd>**LAMBDA Formula: Option 1**</kbd>
[image]

##### #CALC! errors

This formula uses `ARRAYTOTEXT` to avoid the [nested array](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-calc-error-nested-array-ffa5997d-a440-4e41-aae9-8b39c4a8dfb9) `#CALC!` errors.  This workaround limits the number of terms that can be processed.  You should be able to process about 3,500-4,000 words based on your current word length.  If you are processing more than that you could `VSTACK` formulas to resolve ***text too long*** `#CALC!` errors, or you will need a different approach that addresses both issues.

<kbd>**Example of #CALC! Error**</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Example of Stacked Formulas**</kbd>
[image]

##### LAMBDA Formula: Option 2

In order to avoid nested array errors without converting arrays to text, you can employ a `thunk` <sup>[[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)]</sup>   A lambda thunk is *"a lambda function with one parameter containing a lambda function with no parameters"*  <sup>[[flexyourdata.com](https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/what-is-a-thunk-in-an-excel-lambda-function/)]</sup>  This approach is more resource intensive and the formula is more complicated to understand.

Here is an excellent article about lambda thunks from [flexyourdata.com](https://www.flexyourdata.com/) that includes an example formula that I adapted for this answer: [What is a thunk in an Excel lambda function?](https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/what-is-a-thunk-in-an-excel-lambda-function/)

The formula below also filters out many types of errors that might be generated from the source range, in particular missing values.  See the colorized example image at the bottom of the page for more information.

```
=LET( 
   _range, A:B,
   _rng, FILTER(_range,INDEX(_range,,2)<>""),
   _thunk, LAMBDA(x,LAMBDA(x)),
   _thunks, BYROW(_rng, LAMBDA(a, 
   _thunk(MAKEARRAY(1,INDEX(a,1,2),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(a,1,1)))))),
   TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_thunks),MAX(INDEX(_rng,,2)),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(INDEX(_thunks,r,1)(),1,c))),3)
   )
```

Or, wrap it in a lambda and add it as a `Named Formula` to your template.

```
# example named formula

=LAMBDA(_range,
 LET( 
   _rng, FILTER(_range,INDEX(_range,,2)<>""),
   _thunk, LAMBDA(x,LAMBDA(x)),
   _thunks, BYROW(_rng, LAMBDA(a, 
   _thunk(MAKEARRAY(1,INDEX(a,1,2),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(a,1,1)))))),
   TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_thunks),MAX(INDEX(_rng,,2)),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(INDEX(_thunks,r,1)(),1,c))),3)
   ))
```

<kbd>**LAMBDA Formula: Option 2**</kbd>
[image: LAMBDA Formula: Option 2]

<kbd>**Named Formula**</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Named Formula Example**</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Colorized Example: Various Input Values**</kbd>
[image: Colorized Example: Various Input Values]

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of TEXTSPLIT. Unfortunately, I tried it and haven't been able to get anything working, getting errors about nested arrays.

Comment: `=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(type,count,REPT(type & "|",count)))` works to give me an initial array of apples|apples|apples|apples, etc. I then tried to wrap that in another LAMBDA (I'm new to LAMBDA): `=BYROW(A1:A2,LAMBDA(rows,TEXTSPLIT( MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(type,count,REPT(type & "|",count))),,"|",TRUE)))` and I get a #CALC error that "Nested arrays are not supported".

Comment: I also tried `=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(item,quantity,MAKEARRAY(quantity,1,LAMBDA(r,c,item))))` but had the same result (nested array)

Comment: I also tried `=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(item,quantity,SUBSTITUTE(item," ","",SEQUENCE(1,quantity))))` but got the same nested array error

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for understanding the issues involved.  I know the first won't work for my situation due to the character limit.  For the second one, it's possible my situation could involve hundreds of rows (it's a shared template, so no knowing how many rows a user will have, or how long the text will be in each row).  This would make it difficult to break into predictable chunks to vstack together.  Don't suppose you know a way of having the textsplit run on every line, and then vstack put them all together?  I'm guessing we get back into the nested array situation.

Comment: It's a list of budget item descriptions, which would most likely be brief (1-3 words) but on occasion could be a little more detailed. I would imagine most users would have at least a dozen items, but some could have hundreds in a detailed budget. The 'quantity' for each item would be how often the item occurs in the year.  It would more often be a number under 12, but could go as high as 365 if the item occurred very day.

Comment: Wow, impressive!  I'm still wrapping my head around Lambda, so understanding 'Thunks' will take a bit longer, but this formula seems to work for my setup. Thanks a million!

Comment: I added some filtering to allow for ranges that are not the same height as the dataset (forgot that you are using this in a template without knowing the exact dimensions in advance).  Showed example of using a "named formula" to simplify usage e.g. `=namedFormula(range)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution without thunks or TEXTSPLIT.

```
=LAMBDA(in,
    LET(
        dupl, LAMBDA(str, mult, str & T(SEQUENCE(mult))),
        DROP(
            REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)), 
                LAMBDA(a, b, 
                    VSTACK(a, dupl(INDEX(in, b, 1), INDEX(in, b, 2)))
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)
```

The LAMBDA function `dupl` creates a column array containing `mult` copies of the string `str`, while the REDUCE function is applied to an array `SEQUENCE(ROWS(in))`, so that the argument `b` of the LAMBDA function provides the means to access the rows in the table with strings and multiplicities `in`. VSTACK stitches everything together, and the DROP function removes the first row that REDUCE always adds (would be nice if Microsoft would streamline this so that this cleanup isn't necessary). Of course the LET function isn't needed, but I thought the code would be a bit more clear by defining `dupl` explicitly, even if it is only used once in the rest of the code.

Comment: Nice!  Your answer would be improved by showing the steps the average user could use to employ the formula.  Less experienced users will copy and paste it in and not understand why it doesn't work. Also, including empty row handling would be in line with one of the question's parameters: *"I don't know in advance the actual number of rows"*  Great solution.  I encourage you to make your answer more complete, and thank you for teaching me something 

Comment: Agreed, seems like nice solution, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the example I gave above.

Comment: To use my lambda function, one would give it a name in the name manager as explained in Blind Spot's post above (see the part under LAMBDA Formula: Option 2, in particular the screenshot labeled Named Formula). I'll use the name `ExpandTable`. So if the table with strings and multiplicities is contained in the range A2:B4, use the formula `=ExpandTable(A2:B4)` in cell `D1` to obtain the result depicted in column `D` of Blind Spot's examples.

Comment: To handle empty (or otherwise invalid) rows, it's preferable to filter those out before applying the ExpandTable function. E.g., to recreate `D1:D13` in Blind Spots' Colorized Example, enter `=ExpandTable(FILTER(A:B,ISNUMBER(B:B)*(A:A<>"")))` into cell `D1` (of course after defining ExpandTable as a named function). It's not a priori clear what requirements an input row needs to satisfy to be included. E.g., a negative value in the second input column causes an error in ExpandTable, but by filtering those rows out first this can be handled without editing the ExpandTable function.