# Repeat a sequence N times

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table

| Name (Col A) | Start Date (Col B) | End Date (Col C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | 1/31/2023 | 2/2/2023 |
| Name_2 | 1/16/2023 | 1/17/2023 |

and I am trying to change it to a long format, like this:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Name_1 | 1/31/2023 |
| Name_1 | 2/1/2023 |
| Name_1 | 2/2/2023 |
| Name_2 | 1/16/2023 |
| Name_2 | 1/17/2023 |

I tried using sequence & splits, but I can only make it work for the first row, and i want the formula to dynamically add rows in table 2 whenever there is a new line in table 1.

Here is the formula am using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( SPLIT( A2& ","&SEQUENCE(C2-B2+1,1,B2,1),","))
```

I want it in either Google Sheets, but having them both would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Formula

This formula avoids joining and splitting to allow for much larger arrays.  You can see additional detail on the impact in large arrays of joining and splitting in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168065/)

```
=LAMBDA(x, FILTER(x, INDEX(x,,1)<>""))
 ({ FLATTEN(MAP(name, start, end, 
      LAMBDA(n,s,e, ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1,e-s+1),"")&n)))),
    FLATTEN(MAP(start, end,
      LAMBDA(s, e, SEQUENCE(1,e-s+1,s,1)))) })
```

[image]

##### Named Ranges Used

<sup>*I like to use named ranges to reduce the amount of code*</sup>

| Name | Range |
| --- | --- |
| name | A2:A20 |
| start | B2:B20 |
| end | C2:C20 |

##### Code Description

```
Line |  Code
------------------------------------------------------
  1  | =LAMBDA(x, FILTER(x, INDEX(x,,1)<>""))(
  2  |  { 
  3  |    FLATTEN(
  4  |       MAP(name, start, end, 
  5  |         LAMBDA(n, s, e, ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SEQUENCE(e-s+1),"")&n)))),
  6  |     FLATTEN(
  7  |       MAP(start, end,
  8  |         LAMBDA(s, e, SEQUENCE(1,e-s+1,s,1))))
  9  |   })
```

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Line 1** | Wrap **array of names** and **array of dates** in `LAMBDA` function to `FILTER` out `NULL` values: `LAMBDA(x, FILTER(x, INDEX(x,,1)<>""))( [lines_2-9_remaining_code] )` |
| **Line 2** | Open bracket to define array: `{` |
| **Line 3** | Wrap **array of names** in `FLATTEN` function to return a single **column** of names |
| **Line 4** | `MAP` values from 3 columns into **array of names** formula: `name`, `start`, `end` The `start` and `end` values are used to calculate number of copies of `name` needed |
| **Line 5** | Creates an **array of names** from mapped `name`. Date range mapped `[end]-[start]+1` determines `#` of **names** to `SEQUENCE` in array The `ARRAYFORMULA` employed leverages [one approach](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/rept-function/) to creating a text-based array: `ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SEQUENCE([#]),"")&[string])` |
| **Line 6** | Similar to **Line #3**, wrap **array of dates** in `FLATTEN` function to return a single **column** of dates |
| **Line 7** | `MAP` `start` and `end` dates into **array of dates** formula |
| **Line 8** | Use `SEQUENCE(rows, [columns], [start], [step])` to create an array of dates for each pair of mapped values `start` `end` that is: `1` row tall, `[end]-[start]+1` columns wide, begins with the `start` date, and steps by `1` day: `SEQUENCE(1,e-s+1,s,1)` |
| **Line 9** | Close bracket to complete the array `}` |

### Images

---

**Line 7-8**     <sub><sup>*  *without* `FLATTEN`</sup></sub> 
[image]

**Line 6-8**     <sub><sup>*  *including* `FLATTEN`</sup></sub> 
[image]

**Line 6-8**     <sub><sup>*  *including* `LAMBDA` **to** `FILTER` *NULL values*</sup></sub>
[image]

### Resources

---

- Using [ARRAYFORMULA and SEQUENCE instead of REPT](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/rept-function/#:%7E:text=you%20can%20also%20achieve%20this%20affect%20with%20the%20SEQUENCE%20function)
- [Repeat a cell a set number of times](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168065/) (in Excel)

**Google Docs Help:** `FUNCTIONS` used in this answer

| [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) | [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) | [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) | [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985)** | **[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)** | **[SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)** |  |

Comment: Oh that's amazing, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Where can I learn all of these special funcations?

Comment: I added some resources.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Answer edited. I swapped the row and column in the **SEQUENCE** formula for the *array of names* to eliminate the need to **TRANSPOSE** the columns.  ***(A) Formula Before:***  `TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(TEXT(SEQUENCE(e-s+1),"")&n))` ***(B) Formula After:*** `ArrayFormula(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, e-s+1),"")&n)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this:

As a first step, you can use SEQUENCE to connect the days between the two dates. With INDEX and SEQUENCE you allow to join the name with each of the dates:

=IF(A2="","",JOIN("♪",INDEX(A2&"∆"&SEQUENCE(C2-B2+1,1,B2))))

[image]

See that it starts from B2 (the first day), and goes an amount of days equal to the difference +1. I used two different connectors (♪ and ∆) so them you can split them horizontally and vertically. Then with MAP you can do this to repeat through each of the rows:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C, LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,IF(ax="","",JOIN("♪",INDEX(ax&"∆"&SEQUENCE(cx-bx+1,1,bx))))))
```

[image]

Then JOIN to start splitting:

```
=TEXTJOIN("♪",1,MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C, LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,IF(ax="","",JOIN("♪",INDEX(ax&"∆"&SEQUENCE(cx-bx+1,1,bx)))))))
```

[image]

Then you SPLIT:

> =SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♪",1,MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C, LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,IF(ax="","",JOIN("♪",INDEX(ax&"∆"&SEQUENCE(cx-bx+1,1,bx))))))),"♪")

[image]

Transpose and split again:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♪",1,MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C, LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,IF(ax="","",JOIN("♪",INDEX(ax&"∆"&SEQUENCE(cx-bx+1,1,bx))))))),"♪")),"∆"))
```

[image]

Finally, just format that column as date:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's works nicely, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In Google Sheets you can try:

```
=arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A3&"|"&B2:C3),"|"))
```

Excel lacks FLATTEN, but you may be able to do something similar with WRAPROWS/WRAPCOLS.

Comment: Most of the questions asking a formula for "Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel" might need to be closed as "needs more focus". Sometimes, like in this case this could be easily fixed by removing the mentions of one of the apps. In this case, Microsoft Excel was removed due to the formula included by the OP. P.S. When answering with a formula  please include a brief explanation of the key parts and even better if there is an explanation about why it answers the question.

Comment: You missed the sequence part, but thank you.